# Hashtables over large natural language word sets

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, hashtable, libsvm

I'm writing a program in python to do a unigram (and eventually bigram etc) analysis of movie reviews.  The goal is to create feature vectors to feed into libsvm.  I have 50,000 odd unique words in my feature vector (which seems rather large to me, but I ham relatively sure I'm right about that).

I'm using the python dictionary implementation as a hashtable to keep track of new words as I meet them, but I'm noticing an enormous slowdown after the first 1000 odd documents are processed.  Would I have better efficiency (given the distribution of natural language) if I used several smaller hashtable/dictionaries or would it be the same/worse?

More info:

The data is split into 1500 or so documents, 500-ish words each.  There are between 100 and 300 unique words (with respect to all previous documents) in each document.

My current code:

```
#processes each individual file, tok == filename, v == predefined class
def processtok(tok, v):
    #n is the number of unique words so far, 
    #reference is the mapping reference in case I want to add new data later
    #hash is the hashtable
    #statlist is the massive feature vector I'm trying to build
    global n
    global reference
    global hash
    global statlist
    cin=open(tok, 'r')
    statlist=[0]*43990
    statlist[0] = v
    lines = cin.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        line = l.split(" ")
        for word in line:
            if word in hash.keys():
                if statlist[hash[word]] == 0:
                    statlist[hash[word]] = 1
            else:
                hash[word]=n
                n+=1
                ref.write('['+str(word)+','+str(n)+']'+'\n')
                statlist[hash[word]] = 1
    cin.close()
    return statlist
```

Also keep in mind that my input data is about 6mb and my output data is about 300mb.  I'm simply startled at how long this takes, and I feel that it shouldn't be slowing down so dramatically as it's running.

Slowing down: the first 50 documents take about 5 seconds, the last 50 take about 5 minutes.

Comment: The number of documents should be irrelevant. After how many WORDS do you get an enormous slowdown? Are you running out of physical memory? Show us the code that you are using to load this dictionary. Describe what the keys are, and what the values are.

Comment: You really need to explain statlist -- something that (a) is global (b) is initialised in a function once per file (c) returned by that function is not a code smell, it's a code stink! Also 'v == predefined class' needs explanation. Also `reference` is never used.

Comment: statlist is a list of size 43990 which will be my feature vector for the svm.  I declared it as global because I was worried it was causing a memory leak.  I only need that one pointer at a time, though.  the variable reference is just remnants of an older iteration.  Since I'm going to run this through an SVM, I need some training data.  v is the name of the class that the particular document would be in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@ThatGuy has made the fix, but hasn't actually told you this:

The major cause of your slowdown is the line

`if word in hash.keys():`

which laboriously makes a list of all the keys so far, then laboriously searches that list for `word'. The time taken is proportional to the number of keys i.e. the number of unique words found so far. That's why it starts fast and becomes slower and slower.

All you need is `if word in hash:` which in 99.9999999% of cases takes time independent of the number of keys -- one of the major reasons for having a dict.

The faffing about with `statlist[hash[word]]` doesn't help, either. By the way, the fixed size in `statlist=[0]*43990` needs explanation.

**More problems**

Problem A: Either (1) your code suffered from indentation distortion when you published it, or (2) `hash` will never be updated by that function. Quite simply, if `word` is not in `hash` i.e it's the first time you've seen it, absolutely nothing happens. The `hash[word] = n` statement (the ONLY code that updates `hash`) is NOT executed. So no word will ever be in `hash`.

It looks like this block of code needs to be shifted left 4 columns, so that it's aligned with the outer `if`:

```
else:
    hash[word]=n
    ref.write('['+str(word)+','+str(n)+']'+'\n')
    statlist[hash[word]] = 1
```

Problem B: There is no code at all to update `n` (allegedly the number of unique words so far).

I strongly suggest that you take as many of the suggestions that @ThatGuy and I have made as you care to, rip out all the `global` stuff, fix up your code, chuck in a few print statements at salient points, and run it over say 2 documents each of 3 lines with about 4 words in each. Ensure that it is working properly. THEN run it on your big data set (with the prints suppressed). In any case you may want to put out stats (like number of documents, lines, words, unique words, elapsed time, etc) at regular intervals.

**Another problem**

Problem C: I mentioned this in a comment on @ThatGuy's answer, and he agreed with me, but you haven't mentioned taking it up:

```
>>> line = "foo bar foo\n"
>>> line.split(" ")
['foo', 'bar', 'foo\n']
>>> line.split()
['foo', 'bar', 'foo']
>>>
```

Your use of .split(" ") will lead to spurious "words" and distort your statistics, *including the number of unique words that you have*. You may well find the need to change that hard-coded magic number.

I say again: *There is no code that updates `n` in the function* . Doing `hash[word] = n` seems very strange, even if `n` is updated for each document.

Comment: Thanks John.  Given that I found out how many unique words I have, I changed the implementations slightly, since it gives me a more nicely formatted feature vector (43990 == max(n) if I was incrementing n), and yes, there was indentation issues on the way in.  However, my code runs 100 times faster after removing hash.keys.

Comment: @JohnMachin I accidentally removed the line that updates n while stripping out debugging code when I copied the code over.  The problem was solved sufficiently by the first fix (using `hash` instead of `hash.keys()`).  My data is preformatted with newlines etc stripped.

Comment: @piggles: If your data is "preformatted with newlines etc stripped", you must have your own special version of file.readlines() ...

Comment: I was thinking that.  Then I looked at the files and realized that each entire file is exactly one line.

Comment: @piggles: exactly one **unterminated** line, I hope; otherwise you still have the problem, albeit on a much smaller scale. I'd recommend changing to `.split()` anyway, as it works no matter what is in the line.

Comment: well, looking through the data I processed, I didn't have any problems at all and further any data I receive will be processed to the same standards.  In any case, I will rewrite the code.  The only thing that I was worried about was the performance hit I was taking while processing the files.  even at 1400/44000, I'm not going to experience any serious life changing error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Python's Dictionary has anything to do with your slowdown here. Especially when you are saying that the entries are around 100. I am hoping that you are referring to Insertion and Retrival, which are both O(1) in a dictionary. The problem could be that you are not using `iterators` (or loading key,value pairs one at a time) when creating a dictionary and you are loading the entire words in-memory. In that case, the slowdown is due to memory consumption.

Comment: did I say 100? I meant 1000... :-p

Comment: Even then it should not matter as far as dict is concerned. Perhaps you are loading a huge key,value pair entries in memory while constructing a dict.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a few problems going on here.  Mostly, I am unsure of what you are tying to accomplish with statlist.  It seems to me like it is serving as a poor duplicate of your dictionary.  Create it after you have found all of your words.

Here is my guess as to what you want:

```
def processtok(tok, v):
    global n
    global reference
    global hash
    cin=open(tok, 'rb')
    for l in cin:
        line = l.split(" ")
        for word in line:
            if word in hash:
                hash[word] += 1
            else:
                hash[word] = 1
                n += 1
                ref.write('['+str(word)+','+str(n)+']'+'\n')

    cin.close()
    return hash
```

Note, that this means you no longer need an "n" as you can discover this by doing len(n).

Comment: Mostly good ideas, but: (1) change "line" to "words" and "l" to "line" (2) why open in "rb" mode? (3) surely should be `.split()` otherwise the newline will end up attached the last word (4) str(word) is pointless as are the [ and ] (5) you don't need n, just do len(n) -- HUH???

Comment: no I definitely need statlist because I need to create a feature vector for each document (indicating which words appear in each document)

Comment: @piggles - Then you could just use a local dictionary for the file.  Have a hash for all words across the set and a per file dictionary (though I suspect this will not be too elucidating) @John 1) I agree, but I tried to keep it mostly the same 2) I always rb 3) Good point 4) I assume the OP is creating a log of python lists he can reload at any time 5) len(hash)

Comment: (2) You always open text files in binary mode?? Why??? (4) My point was that `word` is already a `str` object.